# How to get response and access the AWS Api with python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, rest

I need to get response from sending request to the AWS. I have the secretkey/AccessKey of AWS.
What is the method/syntax to access the aws APi, for example GetCredentialReport is an API of AWS, How to access this api?

Comment: What do you mean? You can use AWS CLI, SDK, API. In CLI for instance, you use [get-credential-report](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/get-credential-report.html).

Comment: I meant how can you access the getcredentialreport using rest-api with python

Comment: In boto3 there is [get_credential_report](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.get_credential_report).

Comment: do you know boto3 library? Check if you don't they might have some way

Comment: I have'nt used boat library@sandeshdaundkar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `boto3`, which is the aws SDK for Python.

To install it, run in your terminal:

```
pip install boto3
```

In order to get the credentials report, try:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client(service_name='iam', aws_access_key_id="your_access_key",
                              aws_secret_access_key="your_secret_key")
print(client.get_credential_report())
```

If you haven't created the report before, generate it first:

```
client.generate_credential_report()
```

Comment: Thanks@Gabip. But this error pops up when I execute : "botocore.errorfactory.CredentialReportNotPresentException: An error occurred (ReportNotPresent) when calling the GetCredentialReport operation: Unknown
"

Comment: This is not an error in your code but it indicates that the credentials error doesn't exist and if you haven't done it so far, you should generate the report first. Read here for more details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_GetCredentialReport.html

Comment: @Navi I've added it to my post

Comment: @Navi what do you mean by json format? write it to json file?

Comment: So just `import json` and do: `print(json.dumps(client.get_credential_report()))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213078/discussion-between-navi-and-gabip).

Answer (score 1):

You can use get_credential_report() API in boto3 for credential repot

get_credential_report()
Retrieves a credential report for the AWS account. For more information about the credential report, see Getting Credential Reports in the IAM User Guide .

See also: AWS API Documentation

**Request Syntax**

response = client.get_credential_report()

Response Structure

(dict) --
Contains the response to a successful GetCredentialReport request.

Content (bytes) --
Contains the credential report. The report is Base64-encoded.

ReportFormat (string) --
The format (MIME type) of the credential report.

GeneratedTime (datetime) --
The date and time when the credential report was created, in ISO 8601 date-time format.

**Try this code**

import os

import boto3

from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')

AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')

client = boto3.client(
    'iam',
    aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
)

response = client.generate_credential_report()

Comment: tried, but the dotenv is not installing in my working environment

Comment: How to generate for assume_role?